# How can i simulate an click event on the add to wishlist button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to simulate an click event to the add to wishlist button on this page:

[Website url](https://www.interrail.eu/en/plan-your-trip)

What I tried is to trigger an click event specific on the `data-id="22671"` like this:

```
$('a[data-id="22761"]').trigger('click');
```

But this doesn't trigger the action to add the page to wishlist.

Maybe there is an event bound to the document html and can't find the function which add the page to wishlist because of the simulated click.

Can somebody help me out simulating this click?

Comment: i dont find a element with this selector on your given page..

Comment: @Kapsonfire oh lol the data-id is dynamically good that you mentioned. But it is about the anchor add to wishlist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$('a[data-id=22761]')[0].click();`

Comment: Thanks did the work how did i not see that will accept the answer within 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('a span:contains("Add to wish list")').click()`.